# weblogic 10.3.6 to weblogic 12 C upgrade / ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.WhenTag

Tags: java, ejb, jstl, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x

I deployed an EJB stand alone component to weblogic 12 and got the following error:

weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.WhenTag
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:167)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.WhenTag
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:335)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:180)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationForClasses(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:157)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:114)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationsOutsideWebFragment(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:141)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:102)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.processAnnotations(WebAppModule.java:1804)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:763)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:295)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:167)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)

> 

The same ear file deploys fine on weblogic 10. The ear file contains a war because I'm using ServletContextListener to dump some information to the logs on startup. The war file contains the class that implements ServletContextListener and the web.xml, no lib folder.

```
         war
    |            |
meta-inf      web-inf
    |        |       |
manifest   classes web.xml
```

If I package the standard.jar into the lib/war it works on WebLogic 12 but why do I have to do that? This module doesn't use jstl.

Comment: Does you MANIFEST.MF have an entry to jstl or standard jar's ?